# $scope.$on $locationChangeStart keeps URL but shows new view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm having an issue getting the following code snippet to work. This is embedded in a larger application, but the issue is that the following code gets run (I've checked) and will prevent the URL from changing, but the view from the new route is displayed, even if I don't confirm. So I can't actually stay on the same page, even though the URL stays the same. Am I missing a piece of code that is necessary to run this?

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event) {
    if (!confirm("You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave this page without saving?")) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `event.preventDefault();` on `$locationChangeStart`: to stop navigation and when user `confirm`, then redirect.

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, newUrl) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave this page without saving?")) {
        $location.path($location.url(newUrl).hash());
    }
});
```

You can check more in [Cacelling route navigation](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/cancelling-route-navigation-in-angularjs)

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. The issue I'm having isn't that I can't change URLs - the issue is that I'm changing to a different URL even when I don't confirm. As an example, even without the confirm button (when all that is in the $scope.$on is an event.preventDefault()), the page still changes.